# Nuget permissions

Tags: nuget, azure-devops

I have a private Nuget feed in our company Azure DevOps (previously VSTS). I am trying to give a user permissions to just read from the feed. It tells him that he does not have permissions. Am I required to assign a package management license to him to even read from the artifact repository in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is what our organization has found.